# How do you run a script that's located in a parent directory on a file in the current directory?

Tags: bash

My script enters a folder with a bunch of users
/parent/usr/home/fred
once it gets into a specific user like fred it has to run an EX script that's in the /parent directory 
/parent can be anywhere and named anything all I know is it's above usr
The EX script then uses EX to edit the file located in /fred

what I have so far

```
  cd usr
cd home
FOLDERS=*
L=".bash_login"
P=".bash_profile"
for f in $FOLDERS
do
 cd "$f"
 if [ -f ".bash_login" ]
 then 
 grep "/etc/runner" $L >/dev/null 
     if [ $? -eq 0 ]
     then
          #use swap ex
          ex $L <replace.ex
          echo "replaced"
     else
          ex $L <insert.ex
          echo "inserted"
          #use insert at end ex
     fi; 
 else 
    grep "/etc/runner" $P >/dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] 
    then
        # use swap ex
        ex $P <replace.ex
        echo "replaced"
    else 
        ex $P <insert.ex
        echo "inserted"

    fi; 
 fi;
 cd ..
 done
```

Edit: 
Just read about readlink, going to try readlink on the .ex files before the cd into the folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Readlink worked, thank you.

```
#!/bin/bash
replace=$(readlink -f replace.ex)
insert=$(readlink -f insert.ex)
echo $insert
echo $replace
cd usr
cd home
FOLDERS=*
L=".bash_login"
P=".bash_profile"

for f in $FOLDERS
do
 cd "$f"
 if [ -f ".bash_login" ]
 then 
 grep "/etc/runner" $L >/dev/null 
     if [ $? -eq 0 ]
     then
          #use swap ex
          ex $L <$replace
          echo "replaced"
     else
          ex $L <$insert
          echo "inserted"
          #use insert at end ex
     fi; 
 else 
    grep "/etc/runner" $P >/dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] 
    then
        # use swap ex
        ex $P <$replace
        echo "replaced"
    else 
        ex $P <$insert
        echo "inserted"

    fi; 
 fi;
 cd ..
 done
```